# How can I hide the drop-down arrow of a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn like Visual Studio Properties window?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` where one of the columns is a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`. When the grid is populated, that column looks different because of the drop-down arrow appearing on each cell in the column. I'd like to change this so that the drop-down arrow is hidden and only shows up when the row is actually highlighted or when the combobox cell is selected for editing. The behavior I wanted is like how the *Properties* window in *Visual Studio* handles its values.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`, there is a property called `DisplayStyle`. Set it to `Nothing` to hide the DropDownButton

Further information about the `DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle` enumeration is available at this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxdisplaystyle.aspx)

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: Setting `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DisplayStyleForCurrentCellOnly = True` is another option.

Answer (score 3):

If you set `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DisplayStyleForCurrentCellOnly = True`, then the dropdown only appears when the cell is the current cell.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to find this, but the above was the answer mixed with a couple of other pages.

This is how to hide the dropdown from a grid based on a value in a different one.
The valueToCheck must be in a cell before the one containing the dropdown you wish to hide.

```
 Private Sub dgv_CellPainting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
        DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellPainting

    'Pages Grid needs to be edited when rendering
    If (e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex >= 0) Then
        Dim valueToCheck = dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value

        If (valueToCheck <> "True") Then
            Dim thisCol = DirectCast(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
            thisCol.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing
            e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, False)
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```